# Openlayers и линия и маркер

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Привет всем! В OpenLayers поставил маркеры .. координаты которых взяты из базы данных, теперь хочу з тих маркеров построить линию как это сделать?? как вариант можно построить точки, координаты которых будут жестко заданы в коде..и так же по точкам построить линию. может кто знает?

```
    markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Marcadores");
    map.addLayer(markers);

    if (b == 2) 
    {

            var size = new OpenLayers.Size(30, 30);
            var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w / 2), -size.h);

            var location = new OpenLayers.LonLat(kor_1,kor_2).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject());
            var markers2 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(markers);
            var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons-land/vista-map-markers/256/Map-Marker-Ball-Pink-icon.png', size, offset);
            markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(location, icon.clone()));

    }
```

Comment: форматируйте код пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

```
var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Simple Geometry");

var points = [
    location,
    new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(location_x1, location_y1),
    new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(location_x2, location_y2)
];

var lineFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
    new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(points));

vectorLayer.addFeatures([lineFeature]);

map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```